# Android: modify background of Tab header.

Tags: android, tabs

I want to add selector to tab header (not tab body), but without results. May be someone has an example?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do it:

1. Create custom layout:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="64dip"    
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
       >

       <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:paddingTop="7dip"
       />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
           android:paddingBottom="5dip"
       />    
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Add tabs using this layout:

   ```
   private void addTab(String text, int drawable) {
       TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(text);

       View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

       TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
       title.setText(text);
       ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       icon.setImageResource(drawable);

       spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);    

       mTabHost.addTab(spec.setContent(this));

   }
   ```